# New to programming and C

Tags: c, pointers, output

Here is my program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int age = 21;
    float cgpa = 8.92;
    char name = "Karan";

    printf("My Name Is %c", name);
    printf("You are %d years old", age);
    printf("My Avg cgpa is %f", cgpa);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this compiler error:

```
hello.c: In function 'main':
hello.c:6:15: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   char name = "Karan";
               ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: A `char` is a single character. `"Karan"` is an array of `char`

Comment: Yeah, Google for 'C printf format specifiers'

Comment: Please read [ask] on how to select an appropriate title for your question. Your question title does not provide any indication of the topic of your question, other than the programming language (which is already specified by the tag).

Answer (score 4):

"Karan" is a string literal and not a single character.

A string literal is technically an array of characters and the variable holding the string must be a pointer to the character array.

```c
char first_char = 'a';
char second_char = 'b';
printf("First char is %c and second is %c", first_char, second_char);
```

single characters are stored in this way in C and its format specifier is `%c`.

to store strings, you need to declare an array of char or character pointer, which is done by

```c
char* name = "Karan";
printf("My name is %s", name);
```

and its format specifier is `%s`.

Also notice that while declaring a string you use double quotes and while declaring a character, we use a single quotes

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be

```c
char name[<sizeofarray>] = 'Karan';
```

when you declare anything which consists of more than one character. *Karan* had more than one character, so it should be declared as a character array. A character should be declared using '' and a string using "". There is a lot of difference when using '' and "". So be carefull while declaring a character array.